# Upside Down Isosceles Triangle

Tags: java, loops

Answered:

The assignment I was given is to write a Java program that outputs an isosceles triangle based on the users input. For instance, if a user were to input the number 5 after being prompted, the program would output

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

We were instructed to use while loops, but I was not having any success with that. I decided to use for loops instead but am still having trouble. I've declared my variables and have prompted the user for input. Below you will find my for loops. Please help! All my program is doing is printing out a continuous column of pound signs.

```
    //For loop
    for (CountOfRows=UserInput; CountOfRows>0; CountOfRows--)
    {
        System.out.println("# ");
        for (CountOfColumns=UserInput; CountOfColumns>0; CountOfRows++)
        {
            System.out.println("# ");
        }

    }
```

Comment: `println` prints the string you give it plus a newline.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to use a while loop, you can simply do this:

```
while(num > 0){ //stay in loop while the number is positive
    int temp = num; //make a copy of the variable
    while(temp-- > 0) //decrement temp each iteration and print a star
        System.out.print("*"); //note I use print, not println
    System.out.println(); //use println for newline
    num--; //decrement number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your inner for loop so that it runs until the end of the index from the first for loop like this:

```
 int num = 5;

    for (int i = num; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```